# jQuery timer plugin options not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I'm trying to run a jQuery timer plugin in my application but am having problems with setting the options.  Here is the plugin I am using:

[JQuery Countdown plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Attractive-jQuery-Circular-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-TimeCircles.html)

Currently in the Html file I have:

```
<div class="demo" data-timer="5"></div>
```

At the Bottom of the page I have:

```
angular.module('anxietyApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var ts = $(".demo").TimeCircles();
});
```

This is working on my page but I can't seem out how to add in the custom options from the link. It says the available options are:

```
start: true, // determines whether or not TimeCircles should start immediately.
animation: "smooth", // smooth or ticks. The way the circles animate can be either a constant gradual rotating, slowly moving from one second to the other. 
count_past_zero: true, // This option is only really useful for when counting down. What it does is either give you the option to stop the timer, or start counting up after you've hit the predefined date (or your stopwatch hits zero).
circle_bg_color: "#60686F", // determines the color of the background circle.
use_background: true, // sets whether any background circle should be drawn at all. 
fg_width: 0.1, //  sets the width of the foreground circle. 
bg_width: 1.2, // sets the width of the backgroundground circle. 
text_size: 0.07, // This option sets the font size of the text in the circles. 
total_duration: "Auto", // This option can be set to change how much time will fill the largest visible circle.
direction: "Clockwise", // "Clockwise", "Counter-clockwise" or "Both".
use_top_frame: false,
start_angle: 0, // This option can be set to change the starting point from which the circles will fill up. 
time: { //  a group of options that allows you to control the options of each time unit independently.
  Days: {
    show: true,
    text: "Days",
    color: "#FC6"
  },
  Hours: {
    show: true,
    text: "Hours",
    color: "#9CF"
  },
  Minutes: {
    show: true,
    text: "Minutes",
    color: "#BFB"
  },
  Seconds: {
    show: true,
    text: "Seconds",
    color: "#F99"
  }
}
```

I think it is something simple I am just missing where to put the options.

Comment: You can pass options in an object like $(".demo").TimeCircles(obj) where obj is the object with options

Comment: you should never do DOM manipulations in controllers. You can use directive for that.